# Scala: How to pass property of implicit instance of class implicitly?

Tags: scala, implicit

I have following code:

```
object Application {

  case class User(id: Long, username: String)
  case class Request(path: String)
  case class WrappedRequest(user: User, request: Request)

  def updateUserAction(implicit request: WrappedRequest) = {
    updateUser("john@mail.com") // <-- I need request.user to be passed implicitly here
  }

  def updateUser(email: String)(implicit user: User) = {
     println(user.username)
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    implicit val request = WrappedRequest(User(1L, "john"), Request("/"))
    updateUserAction
  }

}
```

From above, is it possible to pass **request.user** in **updateUserAction** method to the **updateUser** method implicitly?

Comment: For the sake of clarity I would suggest to avoid using implicit arguments for this use case. As a programmer I would expect to pass a user to `updateUser` instead of having an implicit user flying around. Nevertheless, I don't know your complete use case, so it might be justified for you.

Answer (score 6):

Make an implicit conversion from `WrappedRequest` to `User` so that all of your methods that require a `WrappedRequest` will have access to an implicit `User`.

```
implicit def req2User(implicit request: WrappedRequest): User = request.user
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
def updateUserAction(implicit request: WrappedRequest) = {
  implicit val user: User = request.user
  updateUser("john@mail.com")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted achieve this without declaring User instance at all, I need something like @m-z answered